# R: read.table and read.csv2 dropping/adding rows. No warnings

Tags: r

I have a datafile of 100,000 rows and 258 columns, delimited by semicolons. `read.table(file, sep=";", fill=T, header=F)` reads in 60,610 rows, and `read.csv2(file, header=F)` shows 100025 rows! `col.names()` using `count.fields()` makes no difference. The weirdest thing is that if I read the data into excel, save as csv, then use `read.csv()`, the import is spot on. But if I change the delimiter to `","` in the original text file and try `read.csv()`, it again reads in only 60,610 rows. No warnings in any of the cases. What's going on?

Comment: Did you try `comment.char = ""` and/or `quote="\""`?

Comment: I suggest you show us the header of the (raw) csv file.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code for `read.csv2` (just type `read.csv` and hit `<enter>` at your R commandline), you'll see it does nothing but call `read.table` with some default values. That should give you a hint on what is happening...

Comment: Okay, but it still doesn't tell me why the commands are dropping/adding rows.

Comment: Well, as per @Marek's comment: the differences are in the other parameters: `quote="\"", dec=",", comment.char=""` for csv2 as opposed to `quote = "\"'", dec = ".", comment.char = "#"`. Your file probably contains one (or more) of these specially interpreted characters (e.g. some lines starting with #, or containing quotes), but it's hard to say without seeing the file.